# How can i redirect to Master View Controller from one view

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

How can i redirect to Master View Controller from one view. Am currently in login page and now i want load PhotoMasterViewController. Can any one tell me how to do that.

Comment: is your MasterViewController the PhotoMasterViewController ??

Comment: hi redirecting means  do u want to add sub view? or by present modal controller or navigation ? what do u prefer to add...

Comment: i need to navigate user to the PhotoMasterViewController page. Any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use "ModalViewController"

it is better than navigationController,you can use like this

```
-(void)NextView:(id)sender
{
PhotoMasterViewController *Photo = [[PhotoMasterViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PhotoMasterViewController" bundle:nil];
//enum, you can choose which style you like
Photo.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:Photo animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your masterViewController add this code and use the pushViewController-

```
-(void)NextView:(id)sender
{
PhotoMasterViewController *Photo = [[PhotoMasterViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PhotoMasterViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:Photo animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: :- Thanks for ur help. But im new to iphone development. so actually i didnt get much idea about the above code. can u please explain how to do that. 

also in my app Delegate, i redirect user to the login screen. and if a user enter password correctly i want to navigate them to the main page(PhotoMasterViewController).

This is my code
if(photoMasterViewController == nil)
        {
            photoMasterViewController = [[PhotoMasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhotoMasterViewController" bundle:nil];
            
 }[self.view addSubview:photoMasterViewController.view];

Comment: @DeepakPillai you might have created a view for going back to ur PhotoViewController rite ?? So add a method in that View.m file from where you need to proceed back to ur PhotoViewController.....

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I got the code i want

UIViewController *rootController = [[MyWordSafeMasterViewController alloc] init];
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];
        
[rootController release];
        
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window addSubview:_navigationController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Also is this the correct way to do it??
once again Thanks all of u :)